# Name of theorem that allows us to construct a Brownian bridge with i.i.d RV's?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, asymptotics, brownian-motion

I am trying to find a theorem which my old teacher showed me a long time ago. The implication of this theorem was that if we had a random sample $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ and we consider the process:

$$B(t) = \sqrt n \sum_{i=1}^t (X_i-\bar{X_n})$$

Is asymptotically a Brownian bridge. The process above was defined using $nt$ instead of just $t$, but I can't recall how... The purpose of this theorem was to construct a Brownian bridge so that we can apply the kolmogorov-smirnov test in order to detect a change in mean.

I've tried google searches but it just leads me to generic papers on brownian bridge and brownian motion.

Comment: This is the invariance principle for random walk bridges. Here is [*the paper*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/24901780) which I guess first proved this result. Also, if you have freedom for the common distribution of the i.i.d. samples $X_i$, then you can choose it to be normal to have a simpler proof as you can give an explicit coupling between your process and the Brownian bridge.

Comment: Ah yes, that's it. The name my teacher called it was Donsker's theorem which appears to be the same thing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The application of Donsker's theorem (from 1951 or so) to Kolmogorov-Smirnov was anticipated (even prompted) by a 1949 paper of Doob: "Heuristic Approach to the Kolmogorov-Smirnov Theorems" appearing in the *Annals of Mathematical Statistics* [https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2236535.pdf]